# Distribution of sum of Indicator Variables

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable, indicator-function

Let $X1 $, $X2 $, $X3 $...$Xn $ be n observations with distribution function $F $. Let $F^{*} $ be the empirical distribution of the random sample.

$F^{*} = \frac{1}{n} \sum I(X_{i} \le x)$ where I = 1, if the equality holds, 0 otherwise.

**i)** Find the distribution of $ \sum I(X_{i} \le x)$

**ii)** Find the limiting distribution of  ${\sqrt(n)} [F^{*}(x)-F(x)]$

**This is my approach;**

Let r observations satisfy the equality and (n-r) observations don't.

$F^{*} = \frac{1}{n} (1+1+..1+0+0+..+0) = \frac{r}{n}$

$  \sum I(X_{i} \le x) = r$

**So distribution is the number of successes in the sample.**

But I'm not sure if this is the way to approach the problem.

**For the 2nd part**;

$ Y =  {\sqrt(n)} [F^{*}(x)-F(x)] = {\sqrt(n)} [r/n - p] = \frac{1}{\sqrt(n)} [r-np]$

$ n \rightarrow \infty , r\rightarrow np$

therefore,

$ (r-np) \sim N(0, \sigma^{2})$

$ Y = \frac{1}{\sqrt(n)} [r-np] \sim N(0, \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n})$

Comment: Hint. The $X_i$ have to be independent for the problem to have meaning. Assuming that is so, then $\Sigma I$ is binomial distributed (you figure out n and p) and (ii) is easily obtained from the CLT for the binomial.

Comment: @GordonSmyth Is p = F(x) . But should I relate that to r?

Comment: @GordonSmyth I have updated it. Please check

Comment: You haven't yet defined what $\sigma^2$ is.

Comment: @GordonSmyth that would be the variance of binomial RV = npq correct?